# Equation of a progressive harmonic wave

Tags: waves

Why is the equation of a progressive harmonic wave given as y=asin(wt-kx)?
At each point on the wave, wouldn't the value of (wt-kx) always be 0?

Comment: What makes you think it will be zero?

Comment: wt=(2*pi/T)*(x/v)                                         kx=(2*pi/lambda)*x, lambda=vT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set x=0 (this means you are looking at the point in space where x=0).

Then y(x=0) = a sin(w*t) .
So at this point, it is clear that the value of the quantity you are observing will vary periodically.You can perform a similar reasoning for every point in space.

Actually, you can also perform a similar reasoning by setting the instant t and observing the "shape" of the wave in space.